# Adding spaces to string based on list

Tags: python, list, split

I have a string `s` and a list of strings, `arr`.
The length of `s` is equal to the total length of strings in `arr`.
I need to split `s` into a list, such that each element in the list has the same length as the corresponding element in `arr`.

For example:

```
s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'

arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']
```

```
expected == ['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Comment: This question currently being [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386083/8239061) on Meta.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is much cleaner to use `iter` with `next`:

```
s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'
arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']
new_s = iter(s)
result = [''.join(next(new_s) for _ in i) for i in arr]
```

Output:

```
['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to do this:

```py
s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'

arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']

expected = []
i = 0
for word in arr:
    expected.append(s[i:i+len(word)])
    i+= len(word)

print(expected)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a simple for loop this can be done as follows:

```
s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'

arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']

start_index = 0
expected = list()
for a in arr:
    expected.append(s[start_index:start_index+len(a)])
    start_index += len(a)

print(expected)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the future, an alternative approach will be to use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (new in Python 3.8):

```
s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'    
arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']

i = 0
expected = [s[i:(i := i+len(word))] for word in arr]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` to get the positions where you want to split the string:

```
>>> s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'
>>> arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']
>>> import itertools
>>> L = list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, arr)))
>>> L
[6, 8, 10, 21, 29]
```

Now if you `zip` the list with itself, you get the intervals:

```
>>> list(zip([0]+L, L))
[(0, 6), (6, 8), (8, 10), (10, 21), (21, 29)]
```

And you just have to use the intervals to split the string:

```
>>> [s[i:j] for i,j in zip([0]+L, L)]
['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 4):

The `itertools` module has a function named [`accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (added in Py 3.2) which helps make this relatively easy:

```
from itertools import accumulate  # added in Py 3.2


s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'
arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']

cuts = tuple(accumulate(len(item) for item in arr))
words = [s[i:j] for i, j in zip((0,)+cuts, cuts)]
print(words)  # -> ['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple loop and use the length of the words as your index:

```
s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'    
arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']

ctr = 0
words = []
for x in arr:
  words.append(s[ctr:len(x) + ctr])
  ctr += len(x)

print(words)

# ['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach :

```
import numpy as np
ar = [0]+list(map(len, arr))
ar = list(np.cumsum(ar))
output_ = [s[i:ar[ar.index(i)+1]] for i in ar[:-1]]
```

**Output** :

```
['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way

```
a,l = 0,[]
for i in map(len,arr):
    l.append(s[a:a+i])
    a+=i
print (l)
#['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 2):

Props to the answer using `iter`. The accumulate answers are my favorite. Here is another accumulate answer using `map` instead of a list comprehension

```py
import itertools

s = 'Pythonisanprogramminglanguage'
arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'qw', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']
ticks = itertools.accumulate(map(len, arr[0:]))
words = list(map(lambda i, x: s[i:len(x) + i], (0,) + tuple(ticks), arr))
```

Output:

```py
['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could collect slices off the front of `s`.

```
output = []

for word in arr:
    i = len(word)
    chunk, s = s[:i], s[i:]
    output.append(chunk)

print(output)  # -> ['Python', 'is', 'an', 'programming', 'language']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach would be to create a regex pattern describing the desired length of words. You can replace every character by `.` (=any character) and surround the words with `()`:

```
arr = ['lkjhgf', 'zx', 'q', 'ertyuiopakk', 'foacdhlc']

import re

pattern = '(' + ')('.join(re.sub('.', '.', word) for word in arr) + ')'
#=> '(......)(..)(.)(...........)(........)'
```

If the pattern matches, you get the desired words in groups directly:

```
s = 'Pythonisaprogramminglanguage'
re.match(pattern, s).groups()
#=> ('Python', 'is', 'a', 'programming', 'language')
```